# Building a Custom API on top of Parse.com?

Tags: api, parse-platform

I'm planning on building a developer API similar to what Uber and Yo have done. Is it possible to build such API if my app's backend is powered by parse.com? I don't want my custom API pointing to parse, but instead my own site.

[I'm planning on using ruby](http://www.andrewhavens.com/posts/20/beginners-guide-to-creating-a-rest-api/), and was wondering if there would be any limitations over other options (not sure what options I have). Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if it is possible using ruby, but I know it's definitely possible to build your own REST API.

[We](http://www.sk8.asia) have decided to go a bit further and wrote a parse-angular seed project for developing web apps. It can be found [here](https://github.com/SK8-PTY-LTD/parse-angular).

After you pulled it, do a `npm install`

As usual, 
cloud code should go into cloud/main.js 
express code: cloud/app.js 
angular code: cloud/public/js/

Note that: You will need to change your `AppId` and `AppKey` in

config/global.json 
 
cloud/public/js/app.js

As for custom apis, you can define your own in cloud/routes/api.js.

At this point you should have a nice parse-angular project set up and good to go. 
If there's anything wrong, please feel free to open a pull request. :)

Comment: Thanks Jack! I'll definitely look into it! Seems promising!

Comment: Thank you @KingPolygon, Please accept the answer if you like it. :)

Comment: Unfortunately I haven't had time to try it out, but once I do, if it works I definitely will!